# Fetching multiple rows from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cheapbook') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');

if (!(is_null(isset($_REQUEST['SearchByBookTitle']) ? $_REQUEST['SearchByBookTitle'] : null))) {

    $Title = $_REQUEST['SearchByBookTitle'];


    $query = "SELECT A.ISBN,title,year,price,publisher,number 
    FROM Book A, Stocks B
    WHERE title='%$Title%' and
    A.ISBN=B.ISBN";

    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['ISBN'];
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['year'];
        echo $row['price'];
        echo $row['publisher'];
        echo $row['number'];
    }

}
?>
```

**Not able to fetch data in while loop. Query is working fine. I am trying to fetch all the attributes data for each row using while loop. However, it is not working. Appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Why do you need to fetch the result twice?

Comment: Why are you calling `mysqli_query()` twice? Why are you calling `mysqli_fetch_row()` once outside of your loop, then looping on it? How many results do you expect? If it's only one, calling `mysqli_fetch_row()` outside of the loop consumes that result; there are no further results for your loop.

Comment: It was redundant.. Let me delete it! but still it makes no difference

Comment: @Chandra Did you read what Chris said?

Comment: I was not knowing the fact that it consumes that result. I have deleted outside loop fetch. It's working fine. Thanks guys! Appreciate your help

Comment: `WHERE title='%$Title%'` that is wrong, using the incorrect operator. You're literally looking for a string equaling `%Title%`.

Comment: now you edited `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and that's a syntax error right there; no closure.

Answer (score -2):

Change this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Error querying database.');
}
```

Then verify if it returns the data

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     var_dump($row);
     ......
```

I hope this helps